# roswtf ERROR Communication with [/foo] raised an error

Tags: ros, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

in the ROS architecture I developed messages are sent and received as expected but when I launch **roswtf** it tells me:

> ERROR Communication with [/foo] raised
> an error

for every node in the graph. The last line says:

> ERROR The following nodes should be
> connected but aren't:

with a list of every single connection in the graph.

As I said, the system works fine, "**rosnode ping** foo" works fine for every single node and if I send message from the console with **rostopic pub** I don't get any error.

Should I simply skip the errors and move on or is there a reasonable explanation? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28886/roswtf-error-communication-with-%5B/foo%5D-raised-an-error/) by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on 2012-03-15**:
I defined all messages in one package and then imported this package where needed. Can this explain the weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running roswtf on a seperate machine such as your laptop?  And are it's IP/Hostname settings correct? [Network setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on 2012-03-05**:
everything runs on the same machine. The problem is still there. rxgraph build the graph correctly and I am able to rosping each node. I don't get any error when I start roscore and messages are successfully sent and received.

**Comment by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on 2012-03-15**:
Thanks for the link, even though it didn't help.